# ActiveX component can't create an object

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am getting error,

> ActiveX component can't create object.

Actually I have VB6 DLLs where business logic resides and I am calling that DLL function in my VB.NET application, all DLLs are dependent on other DLLs. I am getting the error from one of the DLLs

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Usually that error points to a COM dll that is not registered. You need to look at the chain of calls and find out which COM components you need and make sure they are available. [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (from sysinternals) may help you find it when it reads from the registry and can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Four common causes are:

1. You do not have a required TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX file
2. A TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX needed by the project is present but not registered on your system
3. The VB runtimes are an earlier version than the one you need to run the project
4. A required TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX file is corrupt

Do you have access to the troublesome DLL source code?

Answer (score 0):

Also check permissions. The user account that the vb.net application is running under will need permissions to be able to create the vb6 dll

Answer (score 0):

Process Monitor will definately help find the missing DLL, but frequently the task can be achieved more quickly with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).