# Building Arena Simulation Model with External VB program

Tags: vb.net, com, activex

I have a requirement to construct a Arena simulation model using an entirely separated external VB program, instead of using the build-in VBA programming capabilty. I have some progress on building such program, but not satisfied with the behavior.

1. Is it possible to create a Model without starting the Arena.exe?
2. If the program halt for any reason (such as termination of debugging) during the model creation steps, the subsequent call to the CreateObject function failed with result like "Cannot create ActiveX/Com objects". This error still occurs even if I manually kill the Arena.exe via the Task Manager. How to avoid this?

-- Current Code --

```
Try 
    arenaApp = CType(CreateObject("Arena.Application"), Arena.Application)
    arenaModel = arenaApp.Models.Add
    ... some code to build model, adding modules, blah blah blah, ...
    arenaModel.SaveAs(fileName)
Finally
    If (arenaApp IsNot Nothing) Then arenaApp.Quit()
End Try
```

-- Platform --

- Platform: Win 7 64
- Visual Studio: 2010 (Express edition)
- DotNet Framework: 4.0
- Arena version: 13.9
- VB Project Reference: C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockwell Software\Arena\Arena.exe

Thanks very much.

Yam Hon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I cannot answer your question directly. However, I would recommend looking over the following lecture notes regarding Arena Integration and Customization.

   http://dept.lamar.edu/industrial/Underdown/Simulation/ch10.ppt
2. As for the error you are experiencing, these links are not directly related to Arena but might contain a solution regarding the "Cannot create ActiveX/Com objects" error.

   - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319844
   - [ActiveX component can't create an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880867/activex-component-cant-create-an-object)
   - https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=Cannot+create+ActiveX%2FCom+objects+vb.net

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first problems seems still unsolved to me, and I'm learnt to live with it. For ActiveX creation, it is solved.