# Vb6 component on Windows 2003 R2 won't register

Tags: vb6, 64-bit

I'm trying to deploy some Vb6 components on a Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 R2.  I normally run these in a com+ application and I went through the normal routine of creating the COM+ application and adding all the components.  Everything seemed to work fine until I actually tried to use any of the components.  I would some kind of "ActiveX component can't create object" or "Application-defined or object-defined error" or something similar to that.

To remove as many variables a possible I created a very simple VB form to consume the simpliest of the components and tried that.  Nope.  So I created a simple install to install the component, and whooo hoooo it worked.  So I tried one of the more envolved components with high hopes ... but no after the install I still can't call the component successfully.  Using Dependency Walker I discovered that for some reason the msvbvm60.dll is not properly registerd.

I've downloaded VBRUN60.exe and VBRUN60SP6.exe and tried installing them.  Even going so far as to do a run as with the administrator account and removing the check box for "Run this program with restricted access".  I've tried to manually register the msvbvm60.dll in the SysWow64 directory.

Nothing seems to work.  It just won't register.  Does anybody have any suggestions?  At this point I'll try just about anything.

Thanks

Comment: How could the simple component work if `msvbvm60.dll` wasn't registered?

Comment: I don't understand it either.  I can only guess one of two options.  Its a false postive in Dependency Walker or the compenent itself didn't use any calls from the msvbvm60.dll.  If I point Dependency Walker @ msvbvm60.dll it tells me that WER.DLL and IESHIM.DLL are not found and I'm pretty sure those are false positives left over from IE7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering the components manually you need to pay extra attention. As you are on a 64-bit OS there are two versions of regsvr32.exe. When registering VB6 components you must make sure to use the 32-bit version of regsvr32, which is located under the following location:

```
%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe
```

If you just type regsvr32 on the command prompt, normally the 64-bit version is chosen (because %WINDIR%\system32 is contained in the %PATH% environment variable), so please make sure to use the full path as above.

If you are using a 32-bit MSI to install your components, this version will be selected automatically and the registration should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already done, you should give a try to [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) - one of the best tools I have used on dll registering problems.

The following links will provide some usufull clues:

- An [excelent tutorial on using Process Monitor for problem solving](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appv/archive/2008/01/24/process-monitor-hands-on-labs-and-examples.aspx);
- [ActiveX component can't create an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880867/activex-component-cant-create-an-object)
- [RESOLVED! ActiveX Component Can't Create Object: Cube build failure against SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brismith/archive/2007/03/09/activex-component-can-t-create-object-cube-build-failure-against-sql-server-2005-analysis-services.aspx)

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with unregistered components for Visual Basic 6 - although not tried to use the same one as you are mentioning. Manually registering never resolved things, no matter which reg server was used

The problem (eventually) turns out to be Internet Explorer 10. Uninstalling that (due to the way Windows 7 handles IE as Windows updates, this meant unistalling newer versions first to expose the older ones) worked. Afterwards, reinstalling the latest IE brings no problem.